How to create component in v2 addon using command line
I have v2 addon and I was create files manually, I want to be create in terminal to create components, service, utils,…etc.
I tried in v2 addon path of create component but it will get error!
PS C:\V2 Testing\v2-addon> ember generate component sample2
Unknown blueprint: component
I want to be create in terminal to create components, service, utils,…etc.

there is no generator for v2 addons at this time.
i create components by just right clicking a folder and selecting new file

I want to be create in terminal to create components, service, utils,…etc.

all of these can be done with your editor -- no need for a special tool
example: https://github.com/universal-ember/ember-primitives/tree/main/ember-primitives/src
if you have to support non strict mode, make sure you fill out the appReexports plugin options https://github.com/universal-ember/ember-primitives/blob/main/ember-primitives/rollup.config.mjs#L20
defaults:
    addon.appReexports([
      'components/**/*.js',
      'helpers/**/*.js',
      'modifiers/**/*.js',
      'services/**/*.js',
    ]),

also note that utils are not an ember concept and had no business being in the old generator
